# Calculation form needed almost complete

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with radio buttons and checkboxes. Under each radio button is a column of checkboxes that relate to that radio button. What I am looking for is how can I hide the checkboxes that dont relate to that radio button.

Also I have built some total calculations in the form. When a different radio button is selected, I would like to have all ckeck boxes cleared and the total corrected.

Here is my source using bootstrap cdn. You can copy and paste and load into browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calc Form</title>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="span3" >
      <div style="margin-left:20px; height:200px;" class="well">
         <br />
         <div id="subtotal">Sub-Total:</div>
           <div id="tax">Tax:</div>
           <div id="total">Total:</div><br />

      </div>
    </div>
<form id="quote" class="form-horizontal">   
    <div class="span8">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Options</th>
            <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
            <div class="control-group">
               <label class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="controls">
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="444" onchange="calculateTotal()" checked="checked" type="radio">
                  <strong>1 YR</strong><br />
                  $444 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="1332" onchange="calculateTotal()" checked="unchecked" type="radio">
                  <strong>3 YRS.</strong><br />
                  $1332 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="2220" onchange="calculateTotal()" checked="unchecked" type="radio">
                  <strong>5 YRS.</strong><br />
                  $2220 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="2995" onchange="calculateTotal()" checked="unchecked" type="radio">
                  <strong>ULTIMATE</strong><br />
                  $2995 </label>
              </th>
              </div>
            </div>
</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Plus</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-1yr"  value="35" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $35 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-3yr"  value="105" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $105 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-5yr"  value="175" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $175 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Helicopter Option</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-1yr"  value="75" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $75 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-3yr"  value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $225 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-5yr"  value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $375 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>PDD Option</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-1yr"  value="75" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $75 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-3yr"  value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $225 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-5yr"  value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $375 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ground Ambulance Option</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-1yr"  value="75" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $75 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-3yr"  value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $225 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-5yr"  value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $375 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>100 Mile Waiver Option</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-1yr"  value="95" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $95 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-3yr"  value="285" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $285 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-5yr"  value="475" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $475 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p class="text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Continue>></button>
      </p>
    </div>
 </form> </div>
 <script>
 function calculateTotal() 
{
    var subtotalField = document.getElementById("subtotal");
    var mycalc = document.forms["quote"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var subtotal = 0;
    var tax = 0;
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0, length = mycalc.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (mycalc[i].checked) {
            subtotal += parseInt(mycalc[i].value);
        }
    }

    tax = (subtotal * .09).toFixed(2);
    total = (parseFloat(subtotal) + parseFloat(tax)).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = "Sub-Total: $" + subtotal;
    document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "Tax: $" + tax;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total: $" + total;
};
 </script>>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this...took me forever and it is probably very messy but it works. I need to clean it up. Maybe you could help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calc Form</title>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="span3" >
      <div style="margin-left:20px; height:200px;" class="well">
         <br />
         <div id="subtotal">Sub-Total:</div>
           <div id="tax">Tax:</div>
           <div id="total">Total:</div><br />

      </div>
    </div>
<form id="quote" class="form-horizontal">   
    <div class="span8">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Options</th>
            <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
            <div class="control-group">
               <label class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="controls">
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="444" onchange="set_checked(false); calculateTotal(); hide_checkbox1();" checked="checked" type="radio">
                  <strong>1 YR</strong><br />
                  $444 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="1332" onchange="set_checked(false); calculateTotal(); hide_checkbox2();"  checked="unchecked" type="radio">
                  <strong>3 YRS.</strong><br />
                  $1332 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="2220" onchange="set_checked(false); calculateTotal(); hide_checkbox3();" checked="unchecked" type="radio">
                  <strong>5 YRS.</strong><br />
                  $2220 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="2995" onchange="set_checked(false); calculateTotal();" checked="unchecked" type="radio">
                  <strong>ULTIMATE</strong><br />
                  $2995 </label>
              </th>
              </div>
            </div>
</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Plus</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes"   value="35" type="checkbox" class="oneyr" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $35 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes"  class="threeyr"  value="105" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $105 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr"  value="175" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $175 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Helicopter Option</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes"   value="75" type="checkbox" class="oneyr" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $75 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr"  value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $225 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr"  value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $375 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>PDD Option</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="oneyr"   value="75" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $75 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr"  value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $225 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr"  value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $375 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ground Ambulance Option</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="oneyr"  value="75" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $75 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr"  value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $225 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr"  value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $375 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>100 Mile Waiver Option</td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="oneyr"   value="95" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $95 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr"  value="285" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $285 </label></td>
            <td><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr"  value="475" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()"  >
                + $475 </label></td>
            <td>FREE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p class="text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Continue>></button>
      </p>
    </div>
 </form> </div>
<script>
 function calculateTotal() 
{
    var subtotalField = document.getElementById("subtotal");
    var mycalc = document.forms["quote"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var subtotal = 0;
    var tax = 0;
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0, length = mycalc.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (mycalc[i].checked) {
            subtotal += parseInt(mycalc[i].value);
        }
    }

    tax = (subtotal * .09).toFixed(2);
    total = (parseFloat(subtotal) + parseFloat(tax)).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = "Sub-Total: $" + subtotal;
    document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "Tax: $" + tax;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total: $" + total;
};
</script>
<script>
function set_checked(checked) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', checked);
}

 </script>
<script>
function hide_checkbox1() {
    $('input.threeyr').css('display', 'none');
    $('input.fiveyr').css('display', 'none');
    $('input.oneyr').css('display', 'block');
}
</script>
<script>
function hide_checkbox2() {
    $('input.threeyr').css('display', 'block');
    $('input.fiveyr').css('display', 'none');
    $('input.oneyr').css('display', 'none');
}
</script>
<script>
function hide_checkbox3() {
    $('input.threeyr').css('display', 'none');
    $('input.fiveyr').css('display', 'block');
    $('input.oneyr').css('display', 'none');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide elements on a page I would use CSS. I normally do this by wrapping the html in a div with an id (for use by javascript) and a default class.

```
<style>
    div.one {display: none;}
    div.three {display: none;}
    div.five {display: none;}
    div.unlim {display: none;}
    div.div_one div.one {display: block;}
    div.div_three div.three {display:block;}
    div.div_five div.five {display:block;}
    div.div_unlim div.unlim {display:block;}
</style>
```

To get this to work you will have to wrap anything you want to hide in div tags as well. So in this case you'd wrap the stuff inside the tds in divs. Here is a sample of your code I modified:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="div_unlim">
    <div class="span8">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="mytable"> <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Options</th>
            <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
            <div class="control-group">
               <label class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="controls">
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="444" onchange="calculateTotal('one')" checked="checked" type="radio"
              class="one">
                  <strong>1 YR</strong><br />
                  $444 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="1332" onchange="calculateTotal('three')" checked="unchecked" type="radio"
              class="three">
                  <strong>3 YRS.</strong><br />
                  $1332 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="2220" onchange="calculateTotal('five')" checked="unchecked" type="radio"
              class="five">
                  <strong>5 YRS.</strong><br />
                  $2220 </label>
              </th>
              <th><label class="radio inline">
      <input name="rad" value="2995" onchange="calculateTotal('unlim')" checked="unchecked" type="radio"
              class="unlim">
                  <strong>ULTIMATE</strong><br />
                  $2995 </label>
              </th>
              </div>
            </div>
</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Plus</td>
            <td><div class="one"><label class="checkbox">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-1yr" value="35" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal('one')"  >
                + $35 </label></div></td>
            <td><div class="three"><label class="checkbox" class="three">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-3yr" value="105" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal('three')"  >
                + $105 </label><div></td>
            <td><div class="five"><label class="checkbox" class="five">
                <input name="checkboxes" class="type-group type-group-5yr" value="175" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal('five')"  >
                + $175 </label></div></td>
            <td><div class="unlim"><label class="unlim">FREE</label></div></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p class="text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Continue>></button>
      </p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Basically anything wrapped in class 'one' will only be visible when the wrapping div has class 'div_one'.

You can then also use the input class to decide whether to add it to your total. Your javascript would become:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateTotal(cls)
{
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    myDiv.className = "div_" + cls;

    var subtotalField = document.getElementById("subtotal");
    var mycalc = document.forms["quote"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var subtotal = 0;
    var tax = 0;
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0, length = mycalc.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (mycalc[i].checked ) {
            if(  myDiv.className == "div_" + mycalc[i].className )
               subtotal += parseInt(mycalc[i].value);
            else
            {
               switch( myDiv.className )
               {
                  case "div_one": 
                     if( mycalc[i].className == "type-group type-group-1yr" ) 
                        subtotal += parseInt(mycalc[i].value); 
                     break;
                  case "div_three": 
                     if( mycalc[i].className == "type-group type-group-3yr" ) 
                        subtotal += parseInt(mycalc[i].value); 
                     break;
                  case "div_five": 
                    if( mycalc[i].className == "type-group type-group-5yr" ) 
                        subtotal += parseInt(mycalc[i].value); 
                     break;
               }
            }
        }
    }

    tax = (subtotal * .09).toFixed(2);
    total = (parseFloat(subtotal) + parseFloat(tax)).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = "Sub-Total: $" + subtotal;
    document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "Tax: $" + tax;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total: $" + total;
};
</script>
```

Note that this doesn't un-check the checkboxes but does exclude them from the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

@smitty here is my version of your new code. I brought all your show_checkbox functions into one function and added an onload event handler to the html body so when the page loads the checkboxes aren't visible. I also modified the calculateTotal function to only include input values which are visible so if you want you can not uncheck all checkboxes when a different radio button is selected. Might be more user friendly for the user to not have to check boxes over again when comparing pricing (IMO). Hope it's helpful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calc Form</title>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function set_checked(checked) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', checked);
}

function show_checkbox(year) {
    $('input.threeyr').css('display', 'none');
    $('input.fiveyr').css('display', 'none');
    $('input.oneyr').css('display', 'none');
    if( year != null ) $('input.'+year).css('display','block');
}

function calculateTotal() 
{
    var subtotalField = document.getElementById("subtotal");
    var mycalc = document.forms["quote"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var subtotal = 0;
    var tax = 0;
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0, length = mycalc.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (mycalc[i].checked && mycalc.display != 'none') 
        subtotal += parseInt(mycalc[i].value);
    }

    tax = (subtotal * .09).toFixed(2);
    total = (parseFloat(subtotal) + parseFloat(tax)).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = "Sub-Total: $" + subtotal;
    document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "Tax: $" + tax;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total: $" + total;
};
</script>>
</head>

<body onload="show_checkbox();">
 <div class="row">

 <div class="span3" >
 <div style="margin-left:20px; height:200px;" class="well">
 <br />
 <div id="subtotal">Sub-Total:</div>
 <div id="tax">Tax:</div>
 <div id="total">Total:</div><br />

 </div>
 </div>
<form id="quote" class="form-horizontal"> 
 <div class="span8">
 <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="mytable"> <thead>
  <tr>
  <th> Options</th>
  <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
  <div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
 <div class="controls">
  <th><label class="radio inline">
 <input name="rad" value="444" onchange="set_checked(false); calculateTotal(); show_checkbox('oneyr');" checked="checked" type="radio" class="one">
  <strong>1 YR</strong><br />
  $444 </label>
  </th>
  <th><label class="radio inline">
 <input name="rad" value="1332" onchange="set_checked(false); calculateTotal(); show_checkbox('threeyr');" checked="unchecked" type="radio" class="three">
  <strong>3 YRS.</strong><br />
  $1332 </label>
  </th>
  <th><label class="radio inline">
 <input name="rad" value="2220" onchange="set_checked(false); calculateTotal(); show_checkbox('fiveyr');" checked="unchecked" type="radio" class="five">
  <strong>5 YRS.</strong><br />
  $2220 </label>
  </th>
  <th><label class="radio inline">
 <input name="rad" value="2995" onchange="set_checked(false); calculateTotal(); show_checkbox();" checked="unchecked" type="radio" class="unlim">
  <strong>ULTIMATE</strong><br />
  $2995 </label>
  </th>
  </div>
  </div>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>Plus</td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" value="35" type="checkbox" class="oneyr" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $35 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr" value="105" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $105 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr" value="175" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $175 </label></td>
 <td>FREE</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Helicopter Option</td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" value="75" type="checkbox" class="oneyr" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $75 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr" value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $225 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr" value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $375 </label></td>
 <td>FREE</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>PDD Option</td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="oneyr" value="75" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $75 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr" value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $225 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr" value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $375 </label></td>
 <td>FREE</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Ground Ambulance Option</td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="oneyr" value="75" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $75 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr" value="225" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $225 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr" value="375" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $375 </label></td>
 <td>FREE</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>100 Mile Waiver Option</td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="oneyr" value="95" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $95 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="threeyr" value="285" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $285 </label></td>
 <td><label class="checkbox">
  <input name="checkboxes" class="fiveyr" value="475" type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
  + $475 </label></td>
 <td>FREE</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <p class="text-right">
 <button class="btn btn-primary">Continue>></button>
 </p>
 </div>
 </form> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks man that is much better! Any idea on how I could also show that title of the item selected in the well?